# GitLab CI - Run pipeline when the contents of a file changes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a mono-repo with several projects (not my design choice).

Each project has a `.gitlab-ci.yml` setup to run a pipeline when a "version" file is changed.  This is nice because a user can check-in to `stage` or `master` (for a hot-fix) and a build is created and deployed to a test environment.

The problem is when a user does a merge from `master` to `stage` and commits back to `stage` (to pull in any hot-fixes).  This causes ALL the pipelines to run; even for projects that do not have actual content changes.

How do I allow the pipeline to run from `master` and/or `stage` but ONLY when the contents of the "version" file change?  Like when a user changes the version number.

Here is an example of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` (I have 5 of these, 1 for each project in the mono-repo)

```
#
# BUILD-AND-TEST - initial build
#
my-project-build-and-test:
  stage: build-and-test
  script:
    - cd $MY_PROJECT_DIR
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet build
  only:
    changes:
      - "MyProject/.gitlab-ci.VERSION.yml"
  # no needs: here because this is the first step

#
# PUBLISH
#
my-project-publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - cd $MY_PROJECT_DIR
    - dotnet publish --output $MY_PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH --configuration Release
  only:
    changes:
      - "MyProject/.gitlab-ci.VERSION.yml"
  needs:
    - my-project-build-and-test
```

... and so on ...

I am still new to git, GitLab, and CI/pipelines.  Any help would be appreciated!  (I have little say in changing the mono-repo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `.gitlab-ci.yml` will run the test_job only if the file `version` changes.

```
test_job:
  script: echo hello world
  rules:
    - changes:
      - version
```

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

See also
[Run jobs only/except for modifications on a path or file](http://%20https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2018/10/22/gitlab-11-4-released/#run-jobs-codeonlycodecodeexceptcode-for-modifications-on-a-path-or-file)

Comment: Thank you for the info.  This seems to work.  Some projects still re-deploy but I think that is expected.  If the `master` has a hot-fix and I merge from `master` to `stage` and commit `stage` then the CI will fire because the `version` was changed in `stage`.  (The hot-fix version was incremented)

Comment: Follow up question.  Why did `only: changes:` re-deploy everything?  And how is the `rules: -changes` different?  Thank you

Comment: Only/except are deprecated.

Comment: It looks like this will run on subsequent manual triggers of the pipeline for the same commit where the file changed. Is there a way to have this run only once when the file changes, even if that commit is re-run in multiple pipeline runs?

Comment: @AndrewHarvey Not as far as I know. You _could_ keep state somewhere, and abort the run after discovering you're in a subsequent run.